# button click redirect user to another page and POST

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session

When the return button is clicked, I need it to redirect to fine_payment.php page. I've tried header() but it shows: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent..

```
<form action="fine_payment.php" method="post">
     <button type="submit" name="return" id="submit" class="btn btn-info">Return Book </button>
     <input type="hidden" name="return_id" value="<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>"> 
</form>
```

At the same time , i need to run this POST code:

```
if(isset($_POST['return'])){
    $id = $_POST['return_id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM issue_books WHERE id= $id ";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
    {
        $issue_date = strtotime($row['book_issue_date']);
        $due_date = strtotime($row['book_due_date']);
        $return_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

        $days_diff = $return_date - $due_date;
        if($days_diff >=0)
        {
            $_SESSION['day'] = floor($days_diff/(60*60*24));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['return_id']` < where is that taken from?

Comment: I don't see anything being echo'd.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner its in the button form place as well, i've edited. I just include the code that are related to my question..

Comment: Ok thanks. Please consult the duplicate. It contains information on how to deal with this. Seeing you're using sessions, that is most likely the problem, and that is also discussed in the duplicate.